# Why does the succeeding block element's box start from the content of the previous block element's rather than the preceding element's border?

Tags: html, css

I was writing some HTML and styling it when I noticed that the succeeding block element was beginning from the content of the previous block element and not directly after the margin of the previous block-element. I have a block-element and an inline element as a child. The inline element has some padding at the bottom and a border. I create another block element directly after the first and upon inspecting this page I notice the above. Am I missing something? Thanks!

```css
#last-updated-timestamp {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-style: italic;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #e6e6e6;
 margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<div id="profile">
 <span id="last-updated-timestamp">Last updated Jan 1, 2019</span>
</div>

<div id="flex-container">
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add margin/padding to the top/bottom of an inline element, they are treated differently by the browser.

Maybe use `inline-block` instead?

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for answering my question. That does the trick. But if an inline element is wrapped in a <div> and if I have another <div> below this <div> then shouldn't the inline element wrapped within the div (with its border etc.) and the second div be on different lines. Why do I see the second <div> intersecting with the inline element's padding?

Comment: @physio  A `<p>`, `<h1>`, or even an `<hr>` tag will force a linebreak, but `<div>` elements do not carry any space before or after the `<div>` itself.

Comment: @elbrant aren't div's block elements? That means they flow top to bottom unlike inline elements, correct? Which means they are contained on a line of their own, no?

Comment: Both of your `div`s are on their own line, which is how block elements behave. The problem is that you have applied `padding-bottom: 10px` to your `span`. Interestingly the padding pushes the border down, but it doesn't increase the vertical size of the `span` element, so in your example, the border of the `span` is actually outside the `div` that contains it (try putting different color borders on each element). The top of the second `div` is the bottom of the previous `div`.

Comment: @physio `<div>` elements are part of the block structure, but they can appear throughout your page in different areas depending on how you structure the grid system and your CSS styles. By themselves, they do very little.

Comment: @all please see the following for an explanation: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/03/understanding-inline-box-model/